# Guessing Object Type while Deserializing

Tags: c#

I have a few objects serialized *[edit: using BinaryFormatter]* this way

```
Obj_A 1    
Obj_A 2
Obj_A 3
Obj_B 1
Obj_B 2
Obj_B 3
Obj_B 4
```

How many A objects there are before B's is decided by user on Runtime.

While deserializing, I have no way to guess when to switch form Obj_A deseriliazing to Obj_B

I welcome any relevant insight

*EDIT :* Serialization occurs on the flow and numbers of A's and B's is not known beforehand

**ANSWER**
Marc Gravell suggested something I was JUST NOT aware of : 
Why bother at all ? Just let the formatter do the job and test types afterwards.
(I am surprised I was not massively aswered that by people here, so obvious...)

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream("X:\\binary.dump", FileMode.Open);
object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);

if (o.GetType() == typeof(Obj_A))
     ReadTheMSDN(Obj_A);

else if (o.GetType() == typeof(Obj_B))
     KnowObjectsYouHandle(Obj_B);

stream.Close();
```

Another less elegant solution was to force objects to Lists :

```
LIST Obj_A
    Obj_A 1    
    Obj_A 2
    Obj_A 3

LIST Obj_B
    Obj_B 1
    Obj_B 2
    Obj_B 3
    Obj_B 4
```

Comment: What's the format of the serialization? XML?

Comment: Are you in control of the serialization?  Adding a "count" property would make a lot of sense or, if you're in a hierarchical format like Xml, adding a parent element for each type.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention it. Made an edit

Comment: If you are using BinaryFormatter (edit), it should do this for you. Or are you implementing ISerializable?

Comment: @Marc : I mark the struct [Serializable]. How would the binaryformatter do that for me ?

Comment: @mika BinaryFormatter *included* type metadata. You should just need a `List<object>` or similar; it should just work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What serialisation are you using? Various options

- use a serialiser that handles this for you
- use something before each that tells you the type that follows (could be the full type, could be some marker code, or could be the element name (XML), member-name (JSON), etc)
- write the number if A before the As, the number of B before the Bs etc
- if using something like BinaryFormatter or NetDataContractSerializer (which both include type metadata), deserialize it as normal and use GetType() afterwards to find what you were given

Comment: Hi Marc ! (Nice to see u again) Option 1 is not very clear to me. Option 2 is a smart solution but would slow down the process as it forces an inter-recrod between every object. Option3 won't help, since the program serializes on the flow, not in one shot. So the number is not know beforehand

Comment: @mika - I think we've had this conversation before, but I'm still not convinced BinaryFormatter is intended to be used in that fashion... But either way, since it includes type meta it should just work. My advice though? Don't use BinaryFormatter for this... There are serialisers *designed* for streaming...

Comment: @Marc : Yes indeed, I'm intending to give protobuffs a shot, but as of know I have to deal with legacy code. XML is way too slow. For the BinaryFormatter, I have not seen any way to try cast before effectively serilasing (event thoug I have type meta). What is serialized is serialized (Or I missed something)

Comment: @Mika why not cast afterwards, with the benefit of GetType()?

Comment: @Marc: to answer to the question "Why not use GetType", I am hesitating between "Ignorance" and "stupidty". WOuld you post this as and edit to your answer so I can mark it accepted ? (This might help a lost soul like me looking for such an aswer)

Comment: Many many thanks. sorry for not being sharp on that one, I'm confused.